# How do I get culture-neutral type information when reading event viewer content with WMI in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, event-log

I am reading logs from EventViewer using below lines of code.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\WS2012-DE01\root\cimv2",
               "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE  Type ='Error'");
```

above code works fine in `en-US` culture, but will fail in other culture because other culture will be representing `Error` as some other word.

eg: **Error** word in `de-DE` culture(german) represents as **Fehler**. I will be using the same code in different environement. I do not want to maintain a resource file since issue is with only one word or not need a Translator API because of security measures to solve this. Could anyone please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't query filtering by the name of the event type, but filtering by the internal type id:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\WS2012-DE01\root\cimv2",
               "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE EventType=1");
```

You can see the list of possible values for `EventType` in the [documentation of the WMI Win32_NTLogEvent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394226(v=vs.85).aspx).

Note that the property `Type` is a string and contains the type in the local language, while `EventType` is an integer with a fixed meaning like

- 1 = Error
- 2 = Warning
- 3 = Information
- 4 = Security Audit Success
- 5 = Security Audit Failure